# Git alias: how to pass current directory to shell command?

Tags: git, alias, git-bash, git-alias, working-directory

I'm using git bash under Windows, and I would like to make a git alias command that's conceptually something like this:

```
[alias]
    assume_unchanged_below = "!git ls-files -z $dir | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged"
```

Where `$dir` expands out to the current working directory in the bash shell in which `git assume_unchanged_below` was executed.

I.e. if I'm in `C:\somedir\somesubdir` and execute `git assume_unchanged_below` I would want it to be as if I had typed `git ls-files -z C:\somedir\somesubdir | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged`

It seems like it's possible to get the current directory via `git rev-parse --show-prefix`. I also know it's possible to pass arguments using an anonymous function, but I haven't been able to combine these two concepts to get the behavior I want.

For example, if I do this:

```
[alias]
    assume_unchanged_below = "!f() { \
       git ls-files -z $1 | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged; \
    }; f"
```

Then I can type

```
git assume_unchanged_below `git rev-parse --show-prefix`
```

And it behaves as expected (`$1` is correctly expanded to the current working directory).

However, I don't want to have to manually pass `git rev-parse --show-prefix` to the alias, I want it inferred automatically so that I only need to type

```
git assume_unchanged_below
```

have it operate on the current working directory.

I've tried this

```
[alias]
    assume_unchanged_below = "!f() { \
       git ls-files -z $1 | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged; \
    }; f `git rev-parse --show-prefix`"
```

but this does not work correctly; `$1` in `f()` is empty. Presumably this is because the new shell process that is executing `f()` has the repository root directory as its current directory.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do in a git alias, or do I need to make an alias in my .bashrc  instead to accomplish this?

**--------------------
   Update with Answer
--------------------**

@vampire's suggestion of using $GIT_PREFIX worked, because $GIT_PREFIX inherits its value from the git shell from which the original alias was triggered.

Here's a the working example, with embellishments for usability:

```
[alias]
    assumeallbelow = "!f() { \
        if [ x"$1" != x ]; then \
            echo "You cannot specify the directory because this command operates on all files in the current directory and below";  \
            return;  \
        fi;  \
        echo "Marking all files under $GIT_PREFIX as assume-unchanged";  \
        git ls-files -z $GIT_PREFIX | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged; \
    }; f"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git config alias.test '!git ls-files $GIT_PREFIX'
```